# Vagrant. All seems fine, but does not work. No errors, nothing

Tags: windows, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I installed vagrant (vagrant_1.9.7_x86_64.msi) and have installed VirtualBox (VirtualBox-5.1.24-117012-Win) on a Windows 10 64-bit system.
I have verified that all PATH settings are fine. Completely removed both Vagrant and VirtualBox (also the .vagrant.d folder) and re-installed both.
When in a command-box I do something like `vagrant` or `vagrant --version`, nothing happens, no error, just the command prompt on the next line. Strange thing though is, this has worked at one point. It was when I tried to install Homestead for a laravel project and it was pointed out that I should update Vagrant when thing were going wrong.

Anyone with a similar experience?

Comment: try downgrading vagrant and use vagrant 1.9.6; you're not the only one reporting this kind of error on 1.9.7 but I am not sure there's a solution yet

Comment: What I had to do was to uninstall both virtualbox and vagrant, then reinstall first virtualbox then vagrant.

I also used the switch : 
VirtualBox-5.1.24-117012-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, will try some things out tonight

Comment: Downgrading to 1.9.6 solved my problems too. Thanks!

Comment: Same error here. I have downgraded to the 1.9.6 and it starts correctly.